# Why this regex is not greedy in PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace-callback

This regex should match lists just like in Markdown:

```
/((?:(?:(?:^[\+\*\-] )(?:[^\r\n]+))(?:\r|\n?))+)/m
```

It works in Javascript (with `g` flag added) but I have problems porting it to PHP. It does not behave greedy. Here's my example code:

```
$string = preg_replace_callback('`((?:(?:(?:^\* )(?:[^\r\n]+))(?:\r|\n?))+)`m', array(&$this, 'bullet_list'), $string);

function bullet_list($matches) { var_dump($matches) }
```

When I feed to it a list of three lines it displays this:

```
array(2) { [0]=> string(6) "* one " [1]=> string(6) "* one " } array(2) { [0]=> string(6) "* two " [1]=> string(6) "* two " } array(2) { [0]=> string(8) "* three " [1]=> string(8) "* three " }
```

Apparently `var_dump` is being called three times instead of just once as I expect from it since the regex is greedy and must match as many lines as possible. I have tested it on regex101.com.
How do I make it work properly?

Comment: Are those backticks really there?

Comment: @TimPietzcker Backticks as regex modifiers

Comment: @Tim Pietzcker Fixed. Used backslashes to escape backticks when I didn't have to

Comment: Ah, I had seen the backslashes as slashes and got confused :)

Comment: You need to be careful as your match only works if the text starts with the bullet list. It also only matches one list. See my answer if you want to match all lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex won't work correctly if you have `\r\n` newlines in your input text.

The part `(?:\r|\n?)` matches *either* an `\r` *or* an `\n`, but not both. (regex101 treats newlines as `\n` only, so it works there).

Does the following work?

```
/(?:(?:(?:^[+*-] )(?:[^\r\n]+))[\r\n]*)+/m
```

(or, after removal of all the unnecessary non-capturing groups - thanks @M42!)

```
/(?:^[+*-] [^\r\n]+[\r\n]*)+/m
```

Comment: Yes it works but you forgot to wrap the whole expression in parentheses:
`/((?:(?:(?:^[+*-] )(?:[^\r\n]+))[\r\n]*)+)/m`

Comment: @Juribiyan: The outer parens are not necessary

Answer (score 3):

Your regex can be reduced to:

```
(?:^[+*-] [^\r\n]+\R*)+
```

There're no needs to do all these groups.
`\R` means any kind of line break `\n` or `\r` or `\r\n`

*Edit:* `\R` looses its special meaning in a character class. `[\R]` means `R`
*Thanks to HamZa*

Comment: I didn't know about the `\R` shortcut, nice!

Comment: Wouldn't this also match subsequent non-list lines?

Comment: @TimPietzcker: Yes, it's very usefull to shortened regexes. See § Backslash-R options at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_Compatible_Regular_Expressions

Comment: @M42 Unfortunately, `\R` doesn't work in a character class. `[\R]` [will match `R` literally](http://regex101.com/r/pA8nF2).

Comment: @HamZa: Yes, you're right. Too bad... Answer edited accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

This will match all bulleted lines until it gets to the first line that is not bulleted.

```
(?<=^|\R)\*[\s\S]+?(?=$|\R[^*])
```

- `\*` match a bullet where:

  - `(?<=^|\R)` it is preceeded by the start of the string or a newline.
- `[\s|S]+?` match any character non-greedily where

  - `(?=$|\R[^*])` the matched sequence is followed by the end of string or a new line character followed by a *. Essentially this means that the sequence match is complete when a non-bullet line is found or when end of string.

Results:

The resulting matches are shown in the RegexBuddy output below (Regex 101 can't handle it):

[image: regex result]

Comment: [See my previous comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21509533/why-this-regex-is-not-greedy-in-php#comment32480967_21509642) about `\R` in a character class.

Comment: @HamZa thanks very much, that always trips me up. Need to remember it is a positional match.